# How to neatly query by foreing key value with sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

My code is down below. First method works, latter where I want to give category_id as an url parameter cant find a solution. Im new to sequelize as you can tell. Still Im very grateful if some one could help me, please.

```
itemRouter.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const items = await Item.findAll()
    res.json(items) // THIS WORKS FINE
})

itemRouter.get('/ct/:ctid', async (req, res) => {
    const itemsByCategory = await SOMETHING
    res.json(itemsByCategory)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you create association? I'm just gonna pretend that your Item model has association with Category

```
     itemRouter.get('/ct/:ctid', async (req, res) => {
        
        const itemsByCategory = await Item.findAll({
                include: {
                    model: Category,
                    required: true, //for inner join
                    where : {
                        id: req.params.ctid
                    }
                }
            });
            
            return res.json(itemsByCategory)
        })
```

The query: Find all items that has association with Category model and at the same time the Category, that item belongs to, must have id = ctid.

Docs: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html#eager-loading-filtered-at-the-associated-model-level

Comment: Also to get one item you can use ```findOne``` or ```findByPk``` instead of ```findAll```

Comment: @SimoSiren Did my answer help you? If so, can you mark my answer as the right one so I can get Points :D